# Optional params based on generic extends typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm about to make a function that can receive an optional second argument(params), ts should infer the type based on the first argument, for example

If the type of the first argument is equal to "ALERT", then ts should require the second argument as an object with title and onSend

If the type of the first argument is equal to "LOGIN", then the second argument doesnt exist, so ts should not send any error.

I got a way to infer the types but when the DTO send and undefined type, the function shouldnt even send an error.

```
enum Dropups {
  LOGIN,
  ALERT,
}

interface AlertDTO {
  title: string;
  onSend: () => void;
}

type DTOSwitcher<T extends keyof typeof Dropups | undefined> = T extends "ALERT"
  ? AlertDTO
  : undefined;

interface DropupActions {
  openDropup<T extends keyof typeof Dropups>(
    type: T,
    options: DTOSwitcher<T>
  ): void;
}

const openDropup: DropupActions["openDropup"] = (type, options) => {
  return null;
};

openDropup("ALERT", {
  title: "Hey",
  onSend: () => null,
}); // TS infers correct option types

openDropup("LOGIN", undefined) // OK, but doesnt make sense send undefined here.
openDropup("LOGIN"); // NOT OK, but should be. 2 arguments were expected. Second option type should be equal to 'undefined'
```

Tried using optional type on interface. But for the type that should require an second argument, TS doesnt show any type error as expected.

```
interface DropupActions {
  openDropup<T extends keyof typeof Dropups>(
    type: T,
    options?: DTOSwitcher<T>
  ): void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a different approach :

```
// create function parameter first, as tuples :
type openParams = [type: "LOGIN" ] | [type : "ALERT", options: AlertDTO]

// use that tuple as parameters :
interface DropupActions {
  openDropup(...params:openParams): void;
}

const openDropup: DropupActions["openDropup"] = (...params : openParams) : void => {
  return ;
};

openDropup("ALERT", {title: "Hey",onSend: () => null}); 
openDropup("ALERT"); // not compile
openDropup("LOGIN", undefined) // not compile
openDropup("LOGIN");
```

Hope this can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually resolve this with function overloads, like this.
I simplified your returned type as I don't fully understand what you try to achieve, and your question is on the input parameters specifically.

```
enum Dropups { LOGIN, ALERT }

interface AlertDTO {
  title: string;
  onSend: () => void;
}

function openDropup(type: "ALERT", options: AlertDTO): void;
function openDropup(type: "LOGIN"): void;
function openDropup(type: keyof typeof Dropups, options?: AlertDTO): void {
  // Now do something here
}


openDropup("ALERT", { title: "Hey", onSend: () => null,}); // OK
openDropup("LOGIN", undefined) // Not accepted as it makes no sense
openDropup("LOGIN"); // Ok now
```

Also I usually use union types instead of enums as I think they are easier to manage, i.e.

```
type Dropups = "ALERT" | "LOGIN";
```

This would eliminate the `keyof typeof Dropups` part

Hope this helps.